# Mostar na página apenas os usuários com o mesmo id do Administrador

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Boa pessoa,

Eu tenho uma página onde mostra todos os balconistas cadastrados como mostra essa imagem(https://prnt.sc/t972jm).

Na coluna "Unidade" do meu banco ele apresenta a unidade que o balconista trabalha. Eu tenho duas unidades no meu banco como mostra essa imagem (https://prnt.sc/t973n8).

Na minha tabela "usuários" eu tenho uma coluna chamada "id_unidade" que é uma chave estrangeira com a coluna "id" da tabela "unidade" como mostra essa imagem (https://prnt.sc/t977rs).

A minha dúvida é: Como que eu mostro na minha página de balconistas apenas os balconistas que tem o mesmo "id_unidade" do usuário logado? no caso é o usuário administrador que está logado.

**Pra que que eu quero isso?**

O sistema é um sistema de delivery e essa página é a página do administrador. Ele tem a função de cadastrar os balconistas e eu já tenho toda a função pronta e funcionando para puxar no cadastro, a unidade do usuário logado e assim cadastra-lo na mesma unidade do usuário logado. Do jeito que está, todos os balconistas cadastrados aparece na planilha e eu quero que apareça apenas os balconistas da mesma unidade do usuário logado,

---

essa é a função listar que eu tenho para capturar os dados e mostrar na planilha:

```html
<?php 

require_once("../../conexao.php");
$pagina = 'balconistas';

$txtbuscar = @$_POST['txtbuscar'];


echo '
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-sm mt-3 tabelas">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Nome</th>
            <th scope="col">CPF</th>
            <th scope="col">Telefone</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            
            <th scope="col">Unidade</th>
            <th scope="col">Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';

    
        

        //PEGAR A PÁGINA ATUAL
        $itens_pag = intval(@$_POST['itens_pag']);
        if($itens_pag != ''){
            $itens_por_pagina = $itens_pag;
        }
        $pagina_pag = intval(@$_POST['pag']);

        $limite = $pagina_pag * $itens_por_pagina;

        //CAMINHO DA PAGINAÇÃO
        $caminho_pag = 'index.php?acao='.$pagina.'&';

    if($txtbuscar == ''){
        $res = $pdo->query("SELECT * from usuarios where nivel = 'Balconista' order by nome asc LIMIT $limite, $itens_por_pagina");
    }else{
        $txtbuscar = '%'.@$_POST['txtbuscar'].'%';
        $res = $pdo->query("SELECT * from locais where nivel = 'Balconista' and (nome LIKE '$txtbuscar' or cpf LIKE '$txtbuscar') order by nome asc");

    }
    
    $dados = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        //TOTALIZAR OS REGISTROS PARA PAGINAÇÃO
        $res_todos = $pdo->query("SELECT * from usuarios where nivel = 'Balconista'");
        $dados_total = $res_todos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $num_total = count($dados_total);

        //DEFINIR O TOTAL DE PAGINAS
        $num_paginas = ceil($num_total/$itens_por_pagina);


    for ($i=0; $i < count($dados); $i++) { 
            foreach ($dados[$i] as $key => $value) {
            }

            $id = $dados[$i]['id']; 
            $nome = $dados[$i]['nome'];
            $cpf = $dados[$i]['cpf'];
            $telefone = $dados[$i]['telefone'];
            $usuario = $dados[$i]['usuario'];
            $unidade = $dados[$i]['id_unidade'];
            
        

            

echo '
        <tr>

            
            <td>'.$nome.'</td>
            <td>'.$cpf.'</td>
            <td>'.$telefone.'</td>
            <td>'.$usuario.'</td>
            <td>'.$unidade.'</td>
            
            
            <td>
                <a href="index.php?acao='.$pagina.'&funcao=editar&id='.$id.'"><i class="fas fa-edit text-info"></i></a>
                <a href="index.php?acao='.$pagina.'&funcao=excluir&id='.$id.'"><i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>';

    }

echo  '
    </tbody>
</table>
</div> ';


if($txtbuscar == ''){


echo '

<!--ÁREA DA PÁGINAÇÃO -->
<nav class="paginacao" aria-label="Page navigation example">
          <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            <li class="page-item">
              <a class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm mr-1" href="'.$caminho_pag.'pagina=0&itens='.$itens_por_pagina.'" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
            </li>';
            
            for($i=0;$i<$num_paginas;$i++){
            $estilo = "";
            if($pagina_pag >= ($i - 2) and $pagina_pag <= ($i + 2)){


            if($pagina_pag == $i)
              $estilo = "active";

          echo '
             <li class="page-item"><a class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm mr-1 '.$estilo.'" href="'.$caminho_pag.'pagina='.$i.'&itens='.$itens_por_pagina.'">'.($i+1).'</a></li>';
           } }
            
           echo '<li class="page-item">
              <a class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm" href="'.$caminho_pag.'pagina='.($num_paginas-1).'&itens='.$itens_por_pagina.'" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
</nav>

<div align="center">';

if(@$itens_pag == $itens_por_pagina_1){
    $classe_ativa_1 = 'classe_ativa_pag';
}
if(@$itens_pag == $itens_por_pagina_2){
    $classe_ativa_2 = 'classe_ativa_pag';
}
if(@$itens_pag == $itens_por_pagina_3){
    $classe_ativa_3 = 'classe_ativa_pag';
}

echo '
<a href="'.$caminho_pag.'itens='.@$itens_por_pagina_1.'" class="'.@$classe_ativa_1.'" title="Itens para mostrar na paginação">'.$itens_por_pagina_1.'</a> - 
<a href="'.$caminho_pag.'itens='.@$itens_por_pagina_2.'" class="'.@$classe_ativa_2.'" title="Itens para mostrar na paginação">'.$itens_por_pagina_2.'</a> -
<a href="'.$caminho_pag.'itens='.@$itens_por_pagina_3.'" class="'.@$classe_ativa_3.'" title="Itens para mostrar na paginação">'.$itens_por_pagina_3.'</a> -
<small>Itens</small>

</div>


';

}


?>
```

Comment: Acrescenta na SQL: and id_unidade = '$id_unidade_do_adm'..... SELECT * from usuarios where nivel = 'Balconista' and id_unidade = '$id_unidade_do_adm'... logicamente, somente na situação que for conveniente...

Comment: Na SQL do else txtbuscar... você usa a tabela locais ao invés de usuarios....

Comment: Para te ajudar com a resposta "pronta"... precisa de mais informações!

Comment: A variável '$id_unidade_do_adm' precisa ser criada certo? Como que eu crio ela pegando o 'id_unidade' do usuário que está logado? Quais informações você precisa pra conseguir me ajudar melhor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver

Abri uma sessão no início da página para criar a variável de restauração do id do usuário logado:

```html
<?php 
@session_start();
require_once("../../conexao.php");
  

//TRAZER OS DADOS DO CLIENTE
  $cpf_cliente_u = @$_SESSION['cpf_usuario'];
 
  $res2 = $pdo->query("SELECT * from usuarios where cpf = '$cpf_cliente_u'");
  $dados2 = $res2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $id_unidade = @$dados2[0]['id_unidade'];
  
 ?>

<?php
```

Após isso, utilizei a dica do @Duda Gervásio para adicionar a variável no sql que insere o valor na lista.

```html
if($txtbuscar == ''){
        $res = $pdo->query("SELECT * from usuarios where nivel = 'Balconista' and id_unidade = '$id_unidade' order by nome asc LIMIT $limite, $itens_por_pagina");
    }else{
        $txtbuscar = '%'.@$_POST['txtbuscar'].'%';
        $res = $pdo->query("SELECT * from locais where nivel = 'Balconista' and id_unidade = '$id_unidade' and (nome LIKE '$txtbuscar' or cpf LIKE '$txtbuscar') order by nome asc");

    }


    
    $dados = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        //TOTALIZAR OS REGISTROS PARA PAGINAÇÃO
        $res_todos = $pdo->query("SELECT * from usuarios where nivel = 'Balconista' and id_unidade = '$id_unidade'");
```

Comment: Isso aí! Precisaria saber quais informações você tinha disponível, normalmente na sessão mesmo!! Para evitar uma consulta na base só para pegar a id_unidade, você já pode salvar ela na sessão também na hora do login! ;)